# Grep in two or more columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of which I want to know if certain strings appear whithin certain columns and then get their row numbers, for which I'm using:

```
keywords <- c("knowledge management", "gestión del conocimiento")
npox <- grep(paste(keywords, collapse = "|"), full[,c(7)], ignore.case = T)
```

However this does not work with two or more columns only one `full[,c(7)]` any one knows what can I do? 
sample data (csv): https://tempsend.com/rxucj

Comment: I don't know if there has been a problem with your question formatting, but can you edit your question to show us the code you are using? At present we don't know what text you are searching for or in which columns. Thanks.

Comment: Done, columns are specified in `full[,c(7)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `grep` on individual columns, use `grepl` on the whole dataframe as a character matrix. This will return a logical vector. Convert the logical vector to a matrix of the same dimension as the original data frame, then run `which`, specifying `arr.ind = TRUE`. This will give you the row and column of all matches for your regex.

```r
keywords <- c("knowledge management", "gestión del conocimiento")
npox <- grepl(paste(keywords, collapse = "|"), as.matrix(full), ignore.case = T)

which(matrix(npox, nrow = nrow(full)), arr.ind = TRUE)
#>      row col
#> [1,]  16   8
#> [2,]  15   9
#> [3,]  15  10
#> [4,]  16  15
#> [5,]  16  23
```

For example, we can see that there is a match in the 16th row of the 8th column. We can confirm this by doing:

```r
full[16, 8]
#> [1] "The Impact of Human Resource Management Practices, Organisational 
#> Culture, Organisational Innovation and Knowledge Management on Organisational
#> Performance in Large Saudi Organisations: Structural Equation Modeling With 
#> Conceptual Framework"
```

Where we see that "knowledge management" is present in this cell.

If you want to limit your results to certain columns, it is probably easiest to filter out the results afterwards. For example, suppose I store all the matches in `full` to a variable called `matches`:

```r
matches <- which(matrix(npox, nrow = nrow(full)), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

But I am only interested in matches in columns 7, 8 and 9, then I can do:

```r
matches[matches[,'col'] %in% c(7, 8, 9),]
#>      row col
#> [1,]  16   8
#> [2,]  15   9
```

Comment: This is perhaps the most savy answer, question: if I only want the results that involve certain columns do I only subset the resulting df by the column number I need?

Comment: @Roiadams see my update